# Mysql 'where clause' with long tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have designed a website like bit.ly, but a bit different. Written in php with mysql. When I was running it at localhost, everything seemed to work fine, pages loaded in 4.5 milliseconds, and I was as happy as a clam.

I uploaded it to the server, and users started surfing the website, and using it. Everything seemed to work fine untill the main table started reaching millions of rows.

The table is one million of rows length right now (it has to be that way), and growing. The pages that needs that table take 500ms to load... The mysql query is the next:

```
select link
from table
where kind = $kind and kind_idd = $kind_idd and live = 1;
```

It can return more than 1 link, in fact, it usually returns between 10-50 links.

The problem is that where clause. I am sure that mysql should have something to make it faster. I have been asking google and I found indexes, keys, and so on. But I couldn't find a website that explained it for dummies.. If someone could give me an example to make this thing go fast, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the table structure like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the mysql [explain plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)
so that you can see what is happening.

You probably need to ensure that you have indexes on `kind, kind_idd and live` see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: And if your query will always return between 10-50 links, use a `LIMIT 50` to SQL stop searching after this limit.

Comment: Carpet bombing a table with indexes shouldn't be done without first knowing the structure and cardinality.

Comment: Hi! @user2310289 Thank you for your answer. I have clicked on "index" for all the rows you menctioned, in phpmyadmin and still takes time to load :( And the explain doesn't tell me anything

Comment: Post you explain plan result

Comment: @user2310289 Hi!! What I did after reading your answer is to add indexes on those columns, but separately. But now I have just tried this: 'ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX (kind,kind_idd,live)' and it worked!! Now pages load in 1-10 ms! Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: so happy for you, but as @Jack is saying you can not just add indexes willy-nilly as they may in fact have a negative impact.